# Bash - Check of multiple environment variables and list all missing

Tags: bash, shell, devops

I'm working on a few scripts where I need to check for a few environment variables and list all the ones missing. I'm seeing a lot of posts where it would check for one and exit.

```
if [ -z "$BLAH" ]; then
    echo "Missing BLAH"
    exit 1
fi
```

However, I would like to print all the missing ones and then exit if anything is not set. I'm doing something like this right now, Is there any more elegant way to do this?

```
function check_env_vars {
  status=0
  for name in $*; do
    value="${!name}"
    echo "$value"
    if [[ -z "$value" ]]; then
      echo "$name environment variable must not be empty"
      status=1
    fi
  done
  return $status
}

if [[ check_env_vars "BLAH" "BLAH1" "BLAH2" -ne 0 ]]; then
  exit 1
fi
```

Appreciate any thoughts or ideas.

Comment: Re function declaration syntax, see http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/scripting/obsolete

Comment: Since you specifically ask that all variables be checked and empties reported before the script exits, I think you have the gist of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`if` already checks the exit status; that's what it does with `[[ ... ]]` in the first place.

```
if ! check_env_vars "BLAH" "BLAH1" "BLAH2"; then
    exit 1
fi
```

That said, `bash` already has syntax for verifying that a variable is set and non-null:

```
check_vars () {
  for name; do
    : ${!name:?$name must not be empty}
  done
}
```

Comment: : ${!name:?name missing} would throw on the first missing env var, no?

Comment: It would. I take a hard line on failures, though :)